# adding another column for buttons in a loop mysql fetch array

Tags: php, mysqli, datatables

Hi I would like to add icons or buttons (edit and delete) on the last column of my datatable.

here's the HTML code:

```
<table id="product-grid"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Item No.</th>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Unit</th>
          <th>Unit Cost</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>
```

Here's my php query

```
$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
    $nestedData=array();

    $nestedData[] = $row["pro_id"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["pro_name"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["pro_desc"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["unit_name"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["pro_price"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["cat_name"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["quantity"];

    $data[] = $nestedData;
}
```

I want to add it right after `$nestedData[] = $row["quantity"];`

Thanks

Comment: Where's the code where you output `$data` as `td` elements? There you should add your Buttons, Icons etc.

Comment: You want to to add these icons to the last column of your `database` or to the last column of your `HTML table` ?

Comment: I would like to add it on the last column of my html table as "Action"

Answer (score 2):

```
<tr>
<th>Item No.</th>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Unit</th>
<th>Unit Cost</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>

<?php
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
  ?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["pro_id"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["pro_name"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["pro_desc"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["unit_name"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["pro_price"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["cat_name"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["quantity"];?></td>
    <input type = "submit" name="your_button_name" value = "your_button_name">
</tr>    

<?php } ?>
```

use it like this

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>
<th>Item No.</th>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Unit</th>
<th>Unit Cost</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>

<?php
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
  ?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["pro_id"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["pro_name"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["pro_desc"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["unit_name"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["pro_price"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["cat_name"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["quantity"];?></td>
<td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row["pro_id"];?>">Edit</a> <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["pro_id"];?>">Delete</a> </td>

</tr>    

<?php } ?>
```